# LINQ Design and Prototyping

Tags: database, linq

I'm about to start my first LINQ (to Entities) 'enabled' project, and it immediately strikes me how easy it is to draft SQL queries in SQL Server vs. writing and running code to check results.  What do people usually do here?  Prototype in T-SQL then implement in code, or use a tool, or what?

Comment: The trade off is no intellisense in T-SQL, plus you'll have to change your query in LINQ afterwards anyways

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally use LinqPad to prototype, experiment, and learn about LINQ and the queries I need to run. LinqPad lets you query your object model, observe results, and fine tune the SQL statements generated by variations of your query. Its an excellent tool.

http://www.linqpad.net/

Answer (score 1):

Check out [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/).